# Is there a concise, specific name for a transform that consists of rotate, scale and translate?

Tags: geometry, terminology, transformation

I'm working on software that involves transforming between different mapping coordinate systems. In one part of the maths/logic, I have to derive, then apply a transform between two cartesian coordinate systems using a rotate, uniform-scale, translate, and an optional flip operation.

The resulting transformation will preserve angles as well as the aspect-ratio (due to the uniform-scale).

Is there a specific mathematical name for this combined transform? I want to make sure I get the terminology in the code as correct (and succinct) as possible.

Comment: no linear transformation can be a translation

Comment: An affine transformation (perhaps too general, affine can have different scales for different axes, for example).

Comment: @janmarqz you are of course correct, the question has been corrected

Comment: @copper.hat an affine transform is more general, and can include skew as well as non-uniform scaling, which this type of transform explicitly excludes.

Comment: Hmm, rigid body transformation is too specific (no scaling).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Such a thing is commonly called a [similarity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Similarity_%28geometry%29#Similarity_in_Euclidean_space), as it sends a geometric object $X$ to an object that's similar to $X$.

To quote the great Wikipedia,

> A similarity (also called a similarity transformation or similitude) of a Euclidean space is a bijection $f$ from the space onto itself that multiplies all distances by the same positive real number $r$ [...]

You can even distinguish between *direct* similarities, that preserve orientation, and *opposite* similarities, that reverse orientation.

This convention is followed in Needham's *Visual Complex Analysis*, for example:

> A similarity $\mathcal{S}$ is a mapping of the plane to itself that preserves ratios of distances.

Comment: Factoid, if I hadn't started reading that book today, I would have had no idea :)

Comment: This perfectly describes the _properties_ of the transform, but is there a term that describes the transform itself? E.g. a Similar Transformation?

Comment: In the link, a few terms are used and the exact term "similarity," for the map itself, is one of them. "Similarity transformation" and "similitude" are listed also, but are kind of verbose, given the alternative.

Comment: I'm writing software, so verbose is ok as long as it's exact and specific - in fact when it reduces ambiguity it's often a good thing. A non-mathematically educated software developer is more likely to understand `SimilarityTransformation` out of context since they are likely to understand  the term `Transformation` than they are to understand `Similarity` on its own.

Comment: That makes perfect sense then. I'd personally choose `SimilarityTransformation` in that case.

Comment: I've actually ended up with `SimilarityTransform`, since it's standard in software to use `Transform` instead of `Transformation` (`AffineTransform` is a common term used to describe the coefficients/matrix itself).