# Name for affine functions which only shift and scale

Tags: linear-algebra, functions, terminology

Fix a field $\mathbb K$. Is there a name for functions $f: \mathbb K^n \to \mathbb K^n$ given by
$$
f(x) = \alpha x + b,
$$
where $b \in \mathbb K^n$ and $\alpha \in \mathbb K$ (so $\alpha$ is a scalar, not a matrix)?

Comment: Here is a question about a big larger sate of affine transformations: [Is there a concise, specific name for a transform that consists of rotate, scale and translate?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1493303)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called a [**homothety**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homothetic_transformation)

Note the accent is on the second syllable. [LINK](http://www.dailymotion.com/video/x56qxo5)